# if there are 4 different tables and 18 people, how many ways can the people be seated to have at least 4 in each table?

Tags: combinations

For example with 15 people at 3 different tables each seating 5 people, is the number of combinations of seating equal to:
$$\binom{15}5\binom{10}5(4!)^3$$

Comment: Hint: how many groups of what size do we have for this? If you answer that I am confident that similar to your approach you can work out the details for each of these cases.

Comment: Where did $4!$ come from?   More broadly:  what arrangements are the same?  Are the seats numbered, say?  (that's sort of what your formula suggests).

Comment: @lulu that was the example problem, not the title's.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel  Well, I think it is half and half.  I think the $5's$ come from the example problem, and the $4$ was left over from the original.

Comment: if there are 4 different tables and 18 people, how many ways can the people be seated to have at least 4 in each table? I do not know how to solve this quesiton.

Comment: i tried many different methods but do not know.

Comment: The hint proposed by @Jan  is the right way to start.  What possible patterns are there?  You could have $(4,4,4,6)$, say....what other patterns are there?  Then count the ways to populate each type.  (there really aren't many possible patterns).

Comment: I need the solution please. I am stuck.

Comment: Please try to follow the hint you have been given.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to approach the problem, depending on which "universe" of arrangements you are considering: people distinguished/undistinguished, same for seats, same for tables, plus whether the tables are round or linear.

The wording of the problem might be interpreted as un-dinstinguished people, un-d. seats, distinguished tables of unspecified type. That is: how to put 18 balls in 4 distinguished boxes, with no less than 4 balls in each.
If that is the correct interpretation, then two balls are free for being allocated wherever: $4 \cdot 4 /2$ ways.

When this happens in a test at school or elsewhere, it is advisable to accompany the answer with the "interpretation".

*--- Addendum  ---*

*There is some confusion going around here.*

Let repeat @lulu's request and mine that when speaking of *"ways"* it is fundamental to specify which is the *universe of equi-probable events* being considered.

Let me try and clarify with an example.
*In how many ways can you flip a pair of fair coins ?*

a) we consider only the cases "equal outcome" (HH or TT) and "different"(HT), because the coins are not labelled and we cannot distinguish (HT) from (TH). They are equi-probable, on the basis physical considerations.

b) three cases (HH), (TT), (HT): the coins are again not distinguishable; however three results are not equi-probable.

c) the coins are labelled and we distinguish the four cases (HH),(HT),(TT) and (TH).

Then are the "ways" 2, 3 or 4 ?

Note that, when we come to compute the *probability* as No. of favourable results / Tot. number of results, and provided the results are weighted appropriately, for the probability of having "equals" we get $1/2$ in every case.

Now, for the problem posed by OP, there so many possible assumptions that can be made, that an answer in terms of "ways" cannot be given unless carefully specifying the "universe".

Comment: would the solution be:18C4⋅14C4⋅10C4⋅6C6 multiply by3!⋅3!⋅3!⋅5! +18C4⋅14C4⋅10C5⋅5C5 multiply by 3!⋅3!⋅4!⋅4!= solution????

Comment: So, to start 18C4 is the number of ways to accomodate $4$ **distinguishable** people out of $18$ into $4$ **un-distinguishable** tables: is this (part) of the assumptions you take as reference ??

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that:

> **n people can be seated on a round table in (n-1)! ways.**
>   **Proof**:
>   All n seats on a table are alike. Select any person to be seated first. He has only 1 choice of seats (there is only 1 way, whichever seat he chooses).
>    Now, symmetry is broken. So, remaining (n-1) seats can be considered as being in a line, with respect to the seat which was first occupied.
>     So, arrange remaining (n-1) people in a line in (n-1)! ways.

There are 2 possible arrangements: $$4,4,4,6$$ and $$4,4,5,5$$
For, $4,4,4,6$: divide 18 people in these groups:
$$^{18}C_4\cdot^{14}C_4\cdot^{10}C_4\cdot^{6}C_6$$
seat them in: $$3!\cdot3!\cdot3!\cdot5!$$
**But, one table  has 6 people while, other 3 have 4 each, so, select that one table in $^4C_1$ ways.**

For, $4,4,5,5$: divide 18 people in these groups:
$$^{18}C_4\cdot^{14}C_4\cdot^{10}C_5\cdot^{5}C_5$$
seat them in: $$3!\cdot3!\cdot4!\cdot4!$$
**2 tables have 4 while other 2 tables have 5 people. Select 2 out of 4 tables in $^4C_2$ ways.**
 $$(^{18}C_4\cdot^{14}C_4\cdot^{10}C_4\cdot^{6}C_6)(3!\cdot3!\cdot3!\cdot5!)(^4C_1) +(^{18}C_4\cdot^{14}C_4\cdot^{10}C_5\cdot^{5}C_5)(3!\cdot3!\cdot4!\cdot4!)(^4C_2)$$ is the final solution.

Comment: can you help with the main question?if there are 4 different tables and 18 people, how many ways can the people be seated to have at least 4 in each table?

Comment: but for this question, atleast 4 people need to be seated for each table.

Comment: edited, does that help?

Comment: there are many underlying assumptions you shall make explicit: people distinguishable ? circular order around the round table (reflection) matters or not ? etc.

Comment: People are definitely distinguishable, tables and seats are not

Comment: order is already taken care off during arrangements

Comment: whats the final answer?

Comment: the final solution statement

Comment: would the solution be:18C4⋅14C4⋅10C4⋅6C6 multiply by3!⋅3!⋅3!⋅5! +18C4⋅14C4⋅10C5⋅5C5 multiply by 3!⋅3!⋅4!⋅4!= solution????

Comment: along with a factor of 4C1 and 4C2, if your tables are assumed distinguishable; my previous answer was by assuming identical tables

Comment: are you clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Given there are $ 4  $ different tables and $18$ people to be seated with at least $4$ in each  table.

Let us number the tables $ 1,2,3,4$ as all tables are **different**.

if we put at least $ 4 $ in each table we have $ 2 $ extra persons.

Here we have only 2 possible configurations:-

- $(6,4,4,4)$
- $(4,4,5,5)$

For the first one:-
$${^{18}C_6\times^{12}C_4\times^{8}C_4\times^{4}C_4\times{3!}^3\times{5!}\times{4}}$$

Here there are 4 different configurations of the selecting the table, ${\frac{4!}{3!}}$=$4$.

For the second case , $4,4,5,5$:-
$${^{18}C_4\times^{14}C_4\times^{10}C_5\times^{5}C_4\times{3!}^3\times{4!}\times{6}}$$

Here there are 6 different configurations of the selecting the table, ${\frac{4!}{2!\times2!}}$=$6$.

The result is the sum of the above two cases.

Comment: would the solution be:18C4⋅14C4⋅10C4⋅6C6 multiply by3!⋅3!⋅3!⋅5! +18C4⋅14C4⋅10C5⋅5C5 multiply by 3!⋅3!⋅4!⋅4!= solution????

Comment: No, there are not just 2 configurations, in the problem statement, it is not specified that you have to make all 18 seat at the same time. So there may be cases where not all 18 are selected which is dealt in the above explanation.

Comment: so it would just be (3!⋅3!⋅3!⋅5!) + (3!⋅3!⋅4!⋅4!)?

Comment: but if it said all 18 needed to be seated, would it be the first response?

Comment: i am assuming that tables are identical, hence you have only two configurations (4,4,4,6) and (5,5,4,4) .

Comment: you need to assume all 18 seats are occupied, unless mentioned otherwise.

Comment: and your tables seem to be distinguishable, you cant number them

Comment: @omega , in the above statement ,it is mentioned that tables are different, hence there would be 4 configurations related to (4,4,4,6), where 6 comes in every table, and for (5,5,4,4) , we have 6 combinations for different tables that must be taken into consideration.

Comment: ok, if it is so. edited again :(