# if there are 4 different tables and 18 people in total, how many ways can the people be seated to have at least 4 in each table?

Tags: combinatorics

There are 2 possible arrangements:
4,4,4,6
and
4,4,5,5

For, 4,4,4,6: divide 18 people in these groups:
18C4⋅14C4⋅10C4⋅6C6
seat them in:
3!⋅3!⋅3!⋅5!

(note that you dont have a choice in selecting a table, since all 4 are alike)

For, 4,4,5,5: divide 18 people in these groups:
18C4⋅14C4⋅10C5⋅5C5
seat them in:
3!⋅3!⋅4!⋅4!

What would be the final solution statement?

Comment: what would you add or multiply to find the final solution? im confused, please help.

Comment: Don't ask [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2960695/357390) twice! Instead, edit the original question to show your working.

Comment: would the solution be:18C4⋅14C4⋅10C4⋅6C6 multiply by3!⋅3!⋅3!⋅5! +18C4⋅14C4⋅10C5⋅5C5 multiply by 3!⋅3!⋅4!⋅4!= solution????